# Restore deleted desktop files

Tags: command-line, files, restore

Incidentally, I have run a command in the terminal `sudo rm -rf ~/Desktop` and all my files/icons in the desktop are gone. I tried some tools like testdisk and foremost to restore the files but they don't work effective like I want.

How can I restore these files please?

Comment: There are more things you can try at http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files.

Comment: I have tried your suggets but no results man!

Comment: Then honestly there isn't much hope left. Be careful next time when you run a command like `rm -rf`.

Comment: You could consider this a painful, yet wonderful opportunity to implement a personal backup solution for your data, so any future mistakes will not result in lost files.

Comment: @NickWeinberg , thank you with your tips. The files that have been deleted, were not so important, but indeed I need te be carefull the next time with that command. I have made a backup of the mos deleted files in Google Drive.!